# A ball that is on the floor of a bus decelerates as the bus moves forward, Newton's 1st law?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

I am struggling to understand how this could be explained by Newton's first law. According to Newton's first law the ball should stay still relative to someone not on the bus. The ball is not decelerating per se, just not moving.

Comment: Newton's 0-th Law: The following laws fit observations from inertial reference frames.

Comment: The bus is accelerating, so in the bus's refrence frame the ball is de accelerating. To a stationary tree on the road, the ball is not moving... it is stationary.

Answer (score 1):

> ...decelerates...

That's a word you don't need in physics conversations. Any change in velocity is an *acceleration*. We say "decelerate" in casual conversation when the direction of an object's acceleration vector is approximately opposite the direction of its velocity vector (i.e., when the acceleration causes the magnitude of the object's velocity to decrease). But as far as the laws of motion are concerned, deceleration and acceleration are the same thing.

> ...as the bus moves forward

That's an ambiguous description. Probably you are talking about what happens when the bus *accelerates*. If the bus was moving along a highway at constant velocity (no acceleration), and if the ball was sitting on the floor, moving along with the same velocity as the bus, then there would not be much interesting to say about it. Things only get interesting when the velocity of the bus changes (i.e., when the bus accelerates).

> According to Newton's first law the ball should stay still relative to someone not on the bus

If the floor of the bus was frictionless*, and if bus and the ball both are stationary from the point of view of somebody standing on the ground outside the bus, and if the bus then starts to move forward (i.e., when the bus accelerates); the ball should seem to remain stationary** from the observer's point of view. Did somebody tell you that it would be any different?

The reason the ball remains stationary is because no force acts on it to change its velocity. A frictionless floor would not be able to exert any force in the direction of the bus's motion.

---

* In reality, the ball will accelerate, but its acceleration will be less than the acceleration of the bus.  A person outside the bus will see the ball start to move in the same direction that the bus moves, but more slowly. A person who is seated on the bus will see the ball start to roll toward the back.

The reason for the acceleration is that, because of friction between the ball and the floor, the ball must roll in order to move relative to the bus. But because the ball has a non-zero *moment of inertia*, it takes force to make it start or stop rolling.  I'm not going to do the math, but the same force that makes the ball roll will also give it linear acceleration---less acceleration than if it was some other shape, unable to roll, but more than zero.

** Stationary until the ball is whacked by the back of the moving bus.

Comment: +1  for the comment on "decelerate".    It's not defined in physics, and one might decide that it means "negative acceleration" in which case the object could be speeding up or slowing down.   Not defined ... be clear in your writing and don't use words that don't have an agreed-upon definition.    Related:  watch your grammar, and have someone else read what you've written.   I recall one published article where one ambiguous sentence made the entire thing worthless.  (Where were the editors?)  I understand this can be difficult for non-native speakers of English.  No excuse for natives!

Answer (score 0):

Relative to a stationary observer not on the bus, the ball does not move. This is consistent with Newton's First Law because there are no forces acting on the ball (assuming there is no friction between the ball and the bus floor).

Relative to an observer on the bus (and stationary with respect to the bus) the ball appears to accelerate in the opposite direction to the bus's direction of motion. Since there are still no forces acting on the ball, you might ask how this apparent acceleration of the ball is consistent with Newton's First Law. The answer is that Newton's Laws only apply when position, velocity and acceleration are measured relative to an "inertial frame of reference". The bus is not an inertial frame of reference because it is accelerating.

There are two ways to deal with this:

1. When applying Newton's Laws, always measure position, velocity and acceleration relative to an inertial frame of reference.

OR

2. Work in a non-inertial frame of reference but introduce "fictitious forces" so that Newton's Laws still appear to hold. In the case of the ball on the bus, a fictitious force could be invented to explain why the ball accelerates relative to the bus. Centrifugal force is another example of a fictitious force - its is only required if you measure positon etc. relative to a rotating (and hence non-inertial) frame of reference.